# Where does Homebrew put the delete_old_cluster.sh script after upgrading Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

After upgrading Postgres via Homebrew and running `brew postgresql-upgrade-database` to migrate the database, the output shows `Running this script will delete the old cluster's data files: ./delete_old_cluster.sh`

Where can the script `delete_old_cluster.sh` be found? It's not in the current working directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

found mine in **/usr/local/var/log** along with the other installation logs

used this command to find it:

```
find / -name delete_old_cluster.sh
```